# Uploading values into Country,state picklist

Tags: community, picklist

Can we upload values into country state picklist under Data Management? If i'm not wrong i think we can enforce the values using workbench.

Comment: Hi check this maybe could help. https://github.com/emoran/Dependent-State-and-Town

Answer (score 4):

You can add new states and countries under Setup > Data Management > State and Country Picklists, click Configure states and countries. Click New button to add a new country, or click a country name, then New button, to add a state to that country. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_configure.htm&language=en_US

Once states and countries have been added, you can also change certain attributes using the Metadata API: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_addresssettings.htm

Answer (score 0):

"We can configure Country and state picklist values as well as we can add new country and state values.under Configure States and Countries you will have the option to add new countries.  .For more information please refer

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US"

Regards,

Naveen

SSE, Salesforce CI expert group

http://www.autorabit.com